# facebook iOS SDK not in browser

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I was just playing with the iOS sample code of the facebook sdk, however I am seeing a screen like this when I login:

[image]

Now usually in other apps, I don't see the web address and the search bar. I only see facebook in the tab bar. So how can I achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask the Facebook API to authenticate the user, it will try to launch the Facebook app if it's installed; if not, it launches Safari instead.  Since you don't have the FB app installed on the simulator, it's launching Safari on the simulator.

If you test on a device instead that has the FB app, then you'll see it launch that as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the sdk to open facebook in Safari,that's why you  see the address bar.Usually the apps uses facebook to open in webView for authentication.And one more thing,Currently all iphone apps uses Graph Api instead of Facebook Sdk.

Comment: so how do I use the graph API instead of the facebook SDK to authenticate?

Comment: The Authentication steps for faceBook using Graph Api is explained in  [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: what I am confused is that how will facebook bring that page up? So you mean an SSO will always appear in the browser?

Comment: It is the browser's feature that shows the addressBar.In webView we can load the authentication page of facebook without that AddressBar.If you need to open faceBook within an application then you don't need to open the login page in Safari.To open the Facebook in safari you don't need any sdk.